# How to make my app a system app?

Tags: android, root

I can copy my `apk` from SD card to `system/app` using shell command:

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system\n");
out.writeBytes("cat /sdcard/myApp.apk > /system/app/myApp.apk\n");
out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system\n");
out.writeBytes("exit\n");  
out.flush();
process.waitFor();
```

the problem is, my device ignores it because it has no attributes set.

when I change it to **-rw-r--r--** using a root browser, it works!! how do I do this using code ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you know, you won't be able to do that on a non-rooted device. To change the file perms,

```
out.writeBytes("chmod 644 /system/app/myApp.apk\n");
```

Also,

```
out.writeBytes("cat /sdcard/myApp.apk > /system/app/myApp.apk\n");
```

should be:

```
out.writeBytes("cp /sdcard/myApp.apk /system/app/myApp.apk\n");
```

Comment: Anywhere you want after the target file exists. That'd probably be right after the `cp`.

Comment: I tried your solution, It works, but now it sets it to *-rwxr-xr-x*. in contrast with the "desired"  *-rw-r--r--* Is that okay? I don't even know what the difference is.